# How many people did the Phantom of the Opera kill?

Tags: french-language, the-phantom-of-the-opera, gaston-leroux

How many people did the Phantom of the Opera kill?

1. How many people were confirmed as killed by Erik explicitly, either through narration or explicit witness testimomy?
2. How many people were there whose deaths were attributed to Erik without evidence proving his innocence (or word of god doing so), like Joseph Buquet.

*I am only interested in events around Opera House - the question's scope excludes his earlier life before he became the Opera Ghost. Also, Leroux's book only - I'm not interested in the musical or other derived works.*

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure there is no fully confirmed murder. Daroga wasn't bothering Erik before the events of the book and I'm pretty sure he stated he started doing it because Erik wasn't supposed to kill anybody, which means that Erik wasn't killing anybody before as the Phantom, so no official kills.

We have some unofficial deaths though, 3 in total:

- Buquet (obviously)
- That lady (I'm pretty sure it was a lady?) that was crushed by a chandelier. (Erik stated that the chandelier fell on its own, but let's face it - he probably did it)
- And Raoul's brother, though I believe Erik in this case that he didn't do it.

And I'm pretty sure that's all?

Comment: Are there any supporting quotes from the book please?